# Is there a way to import a webservices json to unity?

Tags: json, visual-studio, web-services, unity-game-engine

I'm working on my graduation project
and all I need to do is to make a database that contains photos, information and 3D model of a specific object.

Using a camera, I can scan a QR code that calls its object from this database and display the photo, information and 3D model on the unity scene...I have seen many videos and tried many codes but it didn't help.

Comment: Try breaking up your problem into smaller parts that you can code one at a time.  Once you have some code, come back to stackoverflow with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the web service has open REST APIs, you can use StartCoroutine, yield return and UnityWebRequest to call them within Unity.

You can start off by first adding SimpleJSON to your project
https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON
This will help you to create JSON data for POST/PUT requests, and decipher JSON response data from your GET requests. There's a guide to the setup of SimpleJSON within this page - it's just a simple process of copying over a file to a folder in your project.

As for making calls, here's an example of making a GET request. Try starting with this, and see if you can tailor it to your project. If you get stuck again, post a new question in stackoverflow with the code you tried out, and what you tried to do to solve the issue, and the community can help you out. Good luck!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using SimpleJSON;

public class myExampleCode : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(
            functionToCallRestAPIs(
                (JSONNode JSONresponse) => 
                {
                    functionToHandleApiResponse(JSONresponse);
                },
            )
        );
    }

    private IEnumerator functionToCallRestAPIs(System.Action<JSONNode> callBack)
    {
        //Get ready to call the request
        string myRequestURL = "https://**********" 
        UnityWebRequest WebRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(myRequestURL);
        WebRequest.SetRequestHeader("SomeRequestHeader", "SomeHeaderValue");

        //Send the request
        yield return WebRequest.SendWebRequest();

        //Place response into a JSONNode type
        string JSONstring = WebRequest.downloadHandler.text;
        Debug.Log("JSON string contents --> " + JSONstring);
        JSONNode JSONnode = JSON.Parse(JSONstring);

        //Pass on the JSONNode type variable to the callback
        callBack(JSONnode);
    }

    private void functionToHandleApiResponse(JSONNode APIresponse)
    {
        // Example response -> {"version": "1.0","data": {"sampleArray": ["string value",5,{"name": "sub object"}]}}
        Debug.Log("Data inside the response --> " + APIresponse["data"]["sampleArray"][0].Value)
        // Prints a string containing "string value"
    }
}
```